# Multiple Google maps on single page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I would like to add multiple maps of the Google Maps API to a page of my C# ASP.NET application. However, with my current code, only the last map is shown. All the other divs that should contain a map are empty. As you can see in my code, the maps already have unique names (not on a nice way, but it is unique). Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?
It would be really appreciated.

Initialize Google:

```
protected void loadGoogle()
{
    var googleScript = "function loadScript() {" +
        "var script = document.createElement(\"script\");" +
        "script.type = \"text/javascript\";" +
        "script.src = \"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false& callback=initialize\"; " +
        "document.body.appendChild(script);" +
        "}" +
        "window.onload = loadScript;";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "CreateGoogleMapScript", googleScript, true);
}
```

Create maps (called multiple times):

```
protected void createMap(String mapId, String address)
{
    var script = "function initialize() {" +
        "var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();" +
        "var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);" +
        "var mapOptions" + mapId + " = {" +
        "zoom: 16," +
        "center: latlng," +
        "mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP" +
        "};" +
        " var map" + mapId + " = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(" + mapId + "), mapOptions" + mapId + ");" +

        "var address = \"" + address + "\";" +
        "geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {" +
        "if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {" +
        "map" + mapId + ".setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);" +
        "var marker = new google.maps.Marker({" +
        "map: map" + mapId + "," +
        "position: results[0].geometry.location" +
        "});" +
        "} else {" +
        "alert(\"Geocode was not successful for the following reason: \" + status); " +
        "}" +
        "});" +
        "}";
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "CreateMapScript"+mapId, script, true);
}
```

Called by:

While loop, with a `literal.Text` that adds a new div, followed by `createMap(mapId, address);`

UPDATE:

My new code:

```
 var script = "function initialize() { var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();";                  

            for (int i = 0; i < maps.Count; i++)
            {
                String currentId = maps[i] as String;
                String currentLocation = locations[i] as String;

                script += " " + 
                    "var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(" + 500 + "," + 400 + ");" +
                    "var myOptions = {" +
                        "zoom: 16," +
                        "center: latlng," +
                        "mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP" +
                    "};" +                    
                    "var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(\"" + currentId + "\"), myOptions);" +

                    "var address = \"" + currentLocation + "\";" +
                        "geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {" +
                          "if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {" +
                            "map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);" +
                            "var marker = new google.maps.Marker({" +
                                "map: map," +
                                "position: results[0].geometry.location" +
                            "});" +
                          "} else {" +
                                "alert(\"Geocode was not successful for the following reason: \" + status); " +
                            "}" +
                         "});";
            }
            script += "};";
```

Now all maps are drawn, but only the last map has the right location. The other ones are based on the latlng variable. Why can't the geocoder be used multiple times?

Comment: The first thing to do is to ignore the C# side of things for now, and get the solution working in javascript. Create an array or arrays that hold the information you want and loop through that to create your maps. Once that is working, add in the C#.

Comment: I think you're appending a new 'var latlng' in each loop, which will cause its value to be redifined. Try declaring a unique latlng variable name in each loop, e.g. "var latlng" + i + " = new....".
The same may be needed for myOptions, map and addess too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps just the last `initialize` function is firing in the browser? Try having just 1 initialise function that initialises all your maps.